# Adding a PDF in mapping in informatica developer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to add a PDF as Read object in mappings in Informatica Developer ?

Comment: While i was trying to parse a pdf to xml . . it is showing the PDF read object as a binary while mapping to data transformation, but it is a string in  transformation which is leading to conflict.

Answer (score 1):

pdf is an unstructured file to read.you have to use informatica B2b tool to convert such unstructured file into structured and then read.